# Ответ от form.submit()

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Для скачивания файла без перезагрузки использован известный хак: создаем скрытую форму в скрытом фрейме и её сабмитим. Сервер отвечает: `Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="file.txt"`, и файл скачивается.
Теперь понадобилось этот ответ получить. Как это можно сделать?
Пробовал `form.onload`, `form.onsubmit` - ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам надо ловить

```
$('iframe').load(function(){...});
```

Так как сабмит уходит именно туда и ответ приходит туда же.

Comment: @knes, да. Тоже дошел до этого. Только вот тело этого фрейма никак не могу вытащить что-то. innerHTML содержит пустую строку, хотя в инспекторе HTML в теле уже есть ответ.

Comment: @ray1992, можно просто сразу создавать iframe с ссылкой на файл, также будет загружать.

Comment: Эврика. В параметре передается событие и из него можно вытащить.  
Итого примерно так:  

    frame.onload = function(e) {
       e.target.contentDocument.body.innerHTML; // это и есть ответ.
    }

Comment: @lampa, нужно еще параметры передавать. И желательно через $_POST, поэтому сделана форма.